# homebrew vim 7.4 backspace doesn't work on OSX 10.10.5

Tags: macos, vim, homebrew

I installed vim 7.4 with homebrew on a clean install of OSX 10.10.5.
When I enter insert mode and type some text, I see new text appear as expected. However, when I press backspace while in insert mode, I expect the text to delete. Instead, it just navigates backward, but it doesn't delete text. If I type, I replace the text under the cursor, but the text in front of the cursor remains:

enter insertion mode and type "foo bar"

```
foo bar|
```

press backspace 4 times

```
foo| bar
```

type `tclan`

```
footclan|
```

I also can't move the cursor backwards past my insertion point:

While still in insertion mode, press backspace 4 times.

```
foot|fungus
```

Exit insertion mode, then enter insertion mode again.

type `fungus`

```
footfungus|
```

press backspace 7 times

```
foot|
```

I expect to delete the "t" as well, but I get stuck at my insertion point.

I have no `.vimrc` file. This is a new clean Macbook Pro I just received from my employer. I literally just installed Xcode, homebrew, and then ran `brew install git bash bash-completion vim`.

If I run `/usr/bin/vim`, I get the OSX system vim, which behaves as I expect.

I also posted this as an [issue on homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/46899), and [they say it is supposed to behave this way because without a `vimrc` file, `vim` is supposed to revert to `vi` compatibility](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/46899#issuecomment-163987725).

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? Perhaps try a different one, simply to eliminate it as a source of problems.

Comment: I tried using it with all the defaults on `Terminal.app`. I also switched to `/usr/local/bin/bash` to have `Terminal.app` use my `brew`'s newer `bash`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ echo "set backspace=2" >> ~/.vimrc
```

should solve your problem.

See `:help 'backspace'`.

Comment: Thanks. This works, but I want to understand why everything doesn't work as expected out of the box with homebrew.

Comment: What do you mean? There's nothing unexpected in the behaviour you describe.

Comment: It doesn't behave the same as `/usr/bin/vim`, and it seemed like they should have behaved the same way.

Comment: No, there's no reason to assume that.

Comment: Warning - this will overwrite the contents of the .vimrc file. Use `>>` to append to the file, or just open it in a text editor.

Comment: The answer should be updated with @wonderlr comment - someone will come a cropper with that!